# rails + carrierwave + fog + S3 socket error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I'm having this problem trying to use S3 services with fog and the Jquery File Upload (https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)

The error

```
Excon::Errors::SocketError (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (SocketError)):
```

This occur when i try to call "save" method in the controller. I'm setting carrierwave as follow:

### **config/initializers/carrierwave.rb**

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS', 
    :aws_access_key_id      => 'access_key_here', 
    :aws_secret_access_key  => 'secret_key_here', 
    :region                 => 'eu-east-1'
  }
  config.fog_directory  = 'folder_name_here'
  config.fog_public     = false 
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'}
  config.storage = :fog
end
```

and my uploader just the "config.storage :fog" and the "store_dir"
Now, I have created my bucket already.

Am i missing some configuration?
It doesn't even work on my dev environment.

Please any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Im experiencing this same issue

Howeever Ive double checked my region for my bucket is Ireland so set region to

eu-west-1 

but get this error in log on CREATE

Excon::Errors::SocketError (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (SocketError)):

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The region name is wrong. It should be 'us-east-1'

Comment: Thanks. Hard to get the region name right. Here's a reference:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html

Comment: @Ron why is this not working with other regions? doesnt make sense?

Comment: @YoniGeek it must be set to the region of your bucket. If your Amazon bucket is in 'us-east-1', then using 'eu-east-1' or any other won't work properly.

Comment: Thought 'us-standard' would work, but only 'us-east-1' does. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the link Arcoyle.  Anybody using a server different from default one will get'ya gotcha'd because the S3 admin tools sometimes outright specify 'Ireland'.

Comment: This is only true if the bucket is in Us Standard. In Ireland it would be correct 'eu-west-1'

Comment: yes @dioshari, it is explained in the comments above.

Comment: I don't understand why Amazon lists us-standard as a region when it really isn't one.