# carrierwave + amazon s3 socket error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, carrierwave

My problem is really similar to this one:
[rails + carrierwave + fog + S3 socket error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100909/rails-carrierwave-fog-s3-socket-error)
I was experimenting with regions but without a luck.

I'm trying to use carrierwave + fog + amazon s3 as described on wiki and in few similar questions here on stackoverflow. So, here are my files:

**config/initializers/carrierwave.rb**

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_directory  = 'folder_name_here' # my bucket name

  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS', 
    :aws_access_key_id      => 'access_key_here', # copied from amazon
    :aws_secret_access_key  => 'secret_key_here', # copied from amazon
    :region                 => 'eu-west-1' # my bucket has region set to Ireland
  }
end
```

My uploader has a `storage` parameter set to `:fog`.

And now, when i'll try to save my model, i'm getting the following error:

> getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (SocketError)

Have you any idea what am i possibly doing wrong? If any further info is needed, please just let me know.

Comment: Did you restart your server when adding in the carrierwave and fog  gem?

Comment: well....i have no idea why i allways fogets to restart my server after such modifications. Thank you for your comment, if you wan't to earn few points, post your comment as a reply and i'll mark it as Accepted :)

Comment: No problem! I've done that a few times myself. It's frustrating and even more frustrating with a hint of relief once you figure out what happened. Lol. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you restart your server when adding in the carrierwave and fog gem?